# How to increase the performance of nested foreach loops? While looping the below code is crashing the application

Tags: javascript, performance, loops, foreach

```
 const fData = (selectedData) => {
    const tempData = _tableData; // where tableData is an array of objects
    cont filterData = [];
    tempData.forEach((t) => {
        t.userDetails.forEach((u) => {
            selectedData.forEach((s) => {
                if (s.selCategory === u.userCategory) {
                    filterData.push(u);
                }
            });
        });
    });
  finalDetails(filterData);
};
```

The above code is crashing when we have around 20,000 records, Can we have any other feasible solution?

Comment: Can't you use your server/API to manage the work for you? 20,000 data points on the front end sounds unrealistic.

Comment: No i guess. table data records might me less, while accessing the userdetails  property of that object it might contain so many records i.e., I have to iterate and check for an condition. Where this is failing